# Missing functions in ruby 1.8

Tags: c, ruby, include

I have a ruby gem that I developed with ruby 1.9, and it works. With ruby 1.8, though, it says this when I try to run it:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _RBIGNUM_SIGN
  Referenced from: /Users/Adrian/Desktop/num_to_bytes/ext/num_to_bytes/num_to_bytes.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _RBIGNUM_SIGN
  Referenced from: /Users/Adrian/Desktop/num_to_bytes/ext/num_to_bytes/num_to_bytes.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap
```

If I comment out the line that uses `RBIGNUM_SIGN`, it complains about other functions like `rb_big_modulo`. Some things work, like `NUM2LONG`. Here are some things I have tried:

- In http://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_8_7/ruby.h, `RBIGNUM_SIGN` is defined. But in all versions of ruby I have tried, it is not there.
- I guessed that maybe it was defined in a different .h file. Knowing that Hpricot works with 1.8, I looked at http://github.com/hpricot/hpricot/blob/master/ext/hpricot_scan/hpricot_scan.h. It doesn't include any other files that #define it.
- Putting things like `extern VALUE rb_big_modulo(VALUE x);` at the beginning of my extension don't help.
- Using a brand new Ubuntu installation, I `apt-get`ted ruby, tried to install the gem, and it didn't work either.
- Putting `have_library 'ruby', 'rb_big_modulo'` in my extconf.rb didn't work.

As you can probably see, I am getting desperate (after weeks of trying things!). So, how can I get this to work?

Here is the gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/num_to_bytes

Here is the source: http://gist.github.com/404584

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For `RBIGNUM_SIGN`, define it again in the source.
- For `rb_big_modulo(x, y)`, use `rb_funcall(x, '%', 1, y)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try requiring the [backports](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem. This provides some of the functionality of newer ruby versions for older ruby interpreters.

Comment: That is written in ruby. I am trying to make a C extension.